# Loop over multiple lines in text file in python

Tags: python, file

My assignment is to read a textfile that can have 3+ lines. Each line contains "lastName firstName hours payRate" I take this information and do some calculations, and place it in a formatted python table. Currently I use readlines, split each entry into it's own list and go from there. I have it reading the first entry in the file, but I don't know how to make it do it for each entry in the file.

This is the desired output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yH8Z.png

This is my current code:

```
import os.path
import sys
fileQuestion = input("What is the name of your file?: ")
heading1 = "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:10s}{3:15s}{4:20s}{5:15s}".format("First Name",   "Last Name", "Hours", "Payrate", "Overtime Hours", "Gross Pay")
heading2= "=============================================================================================================="

print(heading1)
print(heading2)

if os.path.isfile(fileQuestion) == True:
    file = open('emps', 'r')
    data = file.readlines()

    for word in data:
        data2= [word.rstrip("\n") for word in data]
        first = data2[0].split()
        lastName = first[0]
        firstName = first[1]
        first[2]=(int(first[2]))
        first[3]=(int(first[3]))
        initialHours = first[2]
        payRate = first[3]

        if initialHours > 40:
            overHours = initialHours - 40
            regHours = 40
            regPay = payRate * regHours
            otPay = overHours * (payRate * 1.5)
            grossPay = regPay + otPay
        else:
            regHours = first[2]
            grossPay = initialHours * payRate
            overHours = 0

        heading3= "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:2d}{3:10d}{4:14d}{5:24.2f}".format(firstName, lastName, regHours, payRate, overHours, grossPay)
        heading4= "{0:15s}{1:21.2f}".format("Total Gross Pay", grossPay)
        heading5= "{0:15s}{1:19.2f}".format("Average Gross Pay", grossPay)
        heading6= "{0:15s}{1:16d}".format("Total Overtime Hours", 33)
        spaceHeading = "               "

        print(heading3)
        print(spaceHeading)
        print(heading4)
        print(heading5)
        print(heading6)
else:
    print("File not found, please retry and start again.")
```

I'm not really sure what to do next, I've tried a couple things but to no avail. Any help would be very useful, thank you.

Comment: You're looping over the entire file for every line in the file. The only reason this doesn't take n^2 time is because the file object is exhausted after the first pass.

Comment: not possible. its the exact same question.

Comment: SO is not a forum - you don't have to make a new question after your previous one is a few hours old. If the answers on your existing question aren't helping you, either comment on them with requests for clarification or edit your question to include more useful information that will lead to more useful answers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help and the stackoverflow pointers. I edited my old post a couple times with better clarity but hadn't received help. This is a time sensitive issue and in my desperation made a new thread. I'll be sure to use this service properly in the future. Thanks again.